# Mutex lock priority between main function and the other threads in pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

We can set thread priority by `pthread_attr_t`, which is the second parameter in [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), but we cannot set the thread priority to the main function by `pthread_attr_t`.

If the main function and the other thread both wait for the mutex lock, which will get the access to the mutex lock **first**?

Comment: Using `pthread_setschedprio()` a thread's priority can be set directly. This includes the "main"-thread.

Comment: Having threads of different priority in one process is asking for trouble, unless you know exactly what you are doing and all possible side effects.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot predict which thread among many will get a mutex first, regardless of their various priorities.

A thread with a higher priority will be run more frequently, and is more ***likely*** to get the lock, there is absolutely no guarantee.

Furthermore, if you ever design code that depends on threads getting locks in a particular order, then you are definitely designing the program incorrectly.